# No sound card available on audio mixer but detected

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After trying many things from different forums/help to get sound on my Dell Inspiron 6400 with Xubuntu 20.04, I still have sound issue:

In audio mixer is available only "output S/PDIF" but when on 'Configuration' Tab I select "Stereo Analog Output (unplugged) (unavailable)" : the sound is ok.

But when I restart, default is still "output S/PDIF" and no sound.

My audio card is detected and is : 82801H (ICH8 Family) STAC9200    options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m21 
I modified the file alsa-base.conf but still not ok...
Try to reload ALSA and PULSE, to re-install, ALSAMIXER not mute...all classical solution exposed.

My goal is just to have sound at startup without the need to change configuration in audio mixer...any idea ? Thanks for you help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing Pulse to use the 'unplugged' interface.
under /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/ there are a bunch of config files pick the right one, which I suspect will be analog-output-speaker-always.conf

and change state.unplugged and state.plugged for the correct interface appropriately - pulse should then just use it. Not sure exactly how to find which one is correct but shouldn't be too many options